# fwrite is returning 0 with "big datas"

Tags: c, cassandra, fwrite

I'm having a problem with a simple fwrite

A little bit of background, Basically i'm recovering and picture data in a Cassandra table which is in Base64 format, the I am using a decoding function which works very well, and I am then writing those data in a "file".jpg, I know it works normally since this algorithm works with an image of 55,6 Kb, I have a problem though when I try to read from a Big Image, I mean an image that is superior to 100Kb (I've done multiple tests with different images).

My problem is that the fwrite (that was working with a small image) is not working and is returning a 0 and perror status is : Bad Adress.

Here is my code, if you need more info, feel free to ask anything ! :

```
while(cass_iterator_next(rows))
             //everything before this is not really important. Every Cass thing are unique to cassandra and are working !
            {
              const CassRow* row = cass_iterator_get_row(rows);
              const CassValue* value = cass_row_get_column_by_name(row, "content");

              CassString keyspace_name;
              cass_value_get_string(value, &keyspace_name);

              //hoolo is a char*, base64 allocate the memory for hoolo77
              //fp is a FILE*.

              hoolo = base64_decode(keyspace_name.data, (int)keyspace_name.length, &hollo);
              fp = fopen("test.jpg", "w+");
              int n = fwrite(hoolo, 1, (int)keyspace_name.length / 4 * 3, fp);


              //I'm doing the x / 4 * 3 operation to have the size of the converted string length
              perror("Error :");
              printf("write !!! : %d\n", n);

              // N = 0 ! 

              fclose(fp);
            }
```

Here a all the definitions :

```
  char  *hoolo;
  size_t *hollo = 0;
```

And here is Base64_decode

```
unsigned char *base64_decode(const char *data,
                             size_t input_length,
                             size_t *output_length) {

  if (decoding_table == NULL)
    build_decoding_table();

  printf("%s\n", data);
  if (input_length % 4 != 0){
    return NULL;
  }
  printf("%d\n", (int)input_length);
  *output_length = input_length / 4 * 3;
  if (data[input_length - 1] == '=') (*output_length)--;
  if (data[input_length - 2] == '=') (*output_length)--;

  unsigned char *decoded_data = malloc(*output_length);
  if (decoded_data == NULL) return NULL;


  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < input_length;) {

    uint32_t sextet_a = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
    uint32_t sextet_b = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
    uint32_t sextet_c = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
    uint32_t sextet_d = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];

    uint32_t triple = (sextet_a << 3 * 6)
      + (sextet_b << 2 * 6)
      + (sextet_c << 1 * 6)
      + (sextet_d << 0 * 6);

    if (j < *output_length) decoded_data[j++] = (triple >> 2 * 8) & 0xFF;
    if (j < *output_length) decoded_data[j++] = (triple >> 1 * 8) & 0xFF;
    if (j < *output_length) decoded_data[j++] = (triple >> 0 * 8) & 0xFF;
  }
  return decoded_data;
}
```

Here is the BT when i try to Printf hoolo

```
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#1  0x00007ffff779a8bc in _IO_puts (str=0xfffffffff7eb3010 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffff7eb3010>) at ioputs.c:36
#2  0x0000000000401381 in main () at select.c:47
```

Comment: you're simply assuming nothing could go wrong. Did you check if `hoolo` is actually what you decoded, or something else, like an error return value?

Comment: @MarcB Hoolo is actually what i decoded I have verified it multiple times and as I said, this code is perfectly working with a smaller image.

Comment: doesn't mean much. small image = different circumstances. maybe the bigger image is exceeding a buffer size or memory limit somewhere.

Comment: please include the actual definitions for all variables

Comment: Try to fwrite not the whole image in one stroke but by chunks of say 1K and check at which chunk fwrite fails. This might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: You are being a bit sloppy with the length of your decoded data: it might be up to two bytes shorter than you are computing (supposing your decoder in fact works correctly).  It is conceivable that when the result is shorter, you are asking `fwrite()` to read from memory that doesn't belong to your program, which would explain the error you received.  I can think of implementation strategies wherein that might happen only for large enough inputs.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `hoolo`, `hollo`, and `base_64_decode` ? Is the length of `keyspace_name.data` always a multiple of 4 (ie. is it padded with `'='` if needed) ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I made the changes ! Sorry i had to go home yesterday

Comment: @MichaelWalz I tried to reduce the write size to 1024, Segemntation Fault on the fwrite().

Comment: On the first fwrite ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz `int n = fwrite(hoolo, 1, (int)keyspace_name.length / 4 * 3, fp);` the One in the first code part

Comment: Show the relevant part of the code by updating your question.

Comment: ... and try `int n = fwrite(hoolo, 1, (int)keyspace_name.length / 4 * 3 / 2, fp);` (writing only half the size, just to see if you still get the error). Also try `malloc(*output_length * 2);` (allocating twice the space needed, just to see what happens).

Comment: @MichaelWalz So i marked where the segmentation is in the question, Maybe you want the BT of GDB ? And i've tried your two things still fwrite returns 0

Comment: Yes, put the GDB BT into your question. And try stripping the `base64_decode` function to a non functional minumum (actually strip the `for` loop) to see if the problem still occurs. But I suspect a heap corruption that has occured somewhere earlier in your program. Or maybe the FILE structure `fp` points to gets corrupted for some reason. The fact that `fwrite`ing only 1024 bytes segfaults also suggests this.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Ok i've added a lot of printf() in the code, first after every line in the base64_decode() even just the before the last return of the decoded_string, and the string has something in it ! But when I try to printf Hoolo (which should be the same thing as decoded_string) back in my main function it's empty and the program segfault I just posted the BT at the end of the question  !